# Is there anything like python's `with` statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

A `with` statement in python is useful for cleaning up resources, e.g.

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
   // do something with the file
```

the writer of the code does not have to worry about closing the file, because writer of the `open` function has implemented necessary stuff to clean up file resources.

What are the common patterns in javascript to achieve this functionality?

Comment: There's nothing *exactly* like `with` in Javascript, no. Its patterns for certain problems will look somewhat different.

Comment: Fun fact: there is a `with` statement in JS, but it is deprecated and doesn't do the same thing as Python's.

Comment: Where would you use something like that? I cant think of any point where some resource is acquired and dropped by the programmer

Comment: A try/catch/finally structure will close the resource whatever happens, but you still have to write the closing code yourself :/

Comment: @DownloadPizza In Node.js, there are several such things (files, db connections, etc.).

Comment: @FZs these are in node, all ecma syntax is browser focused. Also there is no unified thing like pythons `__start__`

Comment: @Download I have no idea what any part of that meant. 

Comment: @deceze ok so basically all the filesystem stuff is by different people, with no way for the language to know how the `with` should apply

Comment: @Download Well, in Python, the `with` statement doesn't really know how files work either; it simply defines a specific protocol that objects can follow to achieve a certain behaviour. That *could* be done in JS too, generally speaking.

Comment: @deceze just to expand on what you said - in Java the try-with-resources statement works the same and C# has `using`. In both cases they just act on the interface. In JS we don't have the same kind of *interfaces* but we do have *protocols* like the iteration protocol. It's the thing that allows us to write `for (let x of xs)` and everything just works, as long as `xs` is an iterable. Similarly, JS can have some sort of closeable protocol and tie it to `cleanUpAfter` language structure (name pending) which will just do the correct closing procedure.

Comment: The [Explicit Resource Management proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-explicit-resource-management) proposes `using const` and `using await const` statements which provide automatic resource management. Once this is available, we'd start to see libraries use it in their interfaces. For libraries that don't make the switch you could write adapters around them and just use the adapters in your code.